# How to access nativeElement attribute using debugeElement in angular unit test

Tags: angular, angular-unit-test

I want to write a simple unit test to check if button is disable when certain value is null or empty.

Below is my spec file:

**test.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Component,
         DebugElement,
         ViewChild }
         from  "@angular/core";

import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { ListCommentsComponent } from './list-comments.component';
import {CommentsDataService} from '../../services/comments/comments-data.service'








describe('ListCommentsComponent', () => {



  let component: ListCommentsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListCommentsComponent>;
  let debugElement:DebugElement;
  let htmlElement:HTMLElement;
  let addCommentBtn:DebugElement;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({

      imports: [ FormsModule, HttpClientModule],

      declarations: [ ListCommentsComponent ],

      providers:[{provide: CommentsDataService}],
     // providers:[HttpClientModule, HttpClient]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListCommentsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();


  });



  fit('should  be disabled when comment is empty', () => {

     component.comment = '';
addCommentBtn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button.addCommentBtn'));



expect(addCommentBtn.nativeElement.getAttribute('disabled')).toBeTruthy();

  });


});
```

**Test failed:**

> Expected undefined to be 'disabled'.

I have searched internet to find debugElement functions to get properties of element but could not find exact solution.

This is a reference similar [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979957/angular-2-tests-get-dom-element-styles)

UPDATE:

Below is HTML of component

**HTML**

```
       <div class="container">
<!--<h1 id="hello"></h1>-->
    <div class="row listCommentsContainer">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8" *ngFor="let commentData of commentsData| async ; let i = index">
          <ol style="list-style: none;">
          <li class="listComments">

            <div  style="display: block">
            <div style="display:inline-block;">
              <a class="avatar">

                <img style="" src="{{commentData.profile_image}}">
              </a>
            </div>
            <a class="commentPostByUserName">
              <span class="commentPostByUserName" style="">{{commentData.first_name}}</span>
            </a>
              <div class="commentTime">{{commentData.time_stamp}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="commentTextDisplay">{{commentData.object}}</div>

            <br>

            <!-- Reply Link -->
            <div class="addReplyContainer" >
              <a  class="addReplyLink"  (click)="showReplyTextArea($event,i )">Reply</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Add Reply -->
            <div [attr.commentId] = "commentData.target_id" *ngIf = "selectedindex == i "
                 class="addReplyContainer replyTextAreaContainer" >
              <textarea [(ngModel)]="reply" style="width:100%"
                        class="replyText commentText addReplyTextarea form-control"></textarea>
              <button [attr.commentId]="commentData.id" [disabled] = "!reply || reply.length>500" class="btn btn-success addCommentBtn" (click)="addReply(commentData.target_id)">Add</button>
            </div>
            <!-- -----Add Reply end------ -->

            <!-- List Replies -->
            <div class="replies col-lg-8 col-sm-8" *ngFor="let reply of commentData.comment">
              <ol style="list-style: none;">
                <li class="listComments listReplies">

                  <div  style="display: block">
                    <div style="display:inline-block;">
                      <a class="avatar">

                        <img style="" src="{{reply.profile_image}}">
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <a class="commentPostByUserName">
                      <span class="commentPostByUserName" style="">{{reply.first_name}}</span>
                    </a>

                  </div>
                  <div class="commentTextDisplay replyTextDisplay">{{reply.object}}</div>
                </li>
              </ol>
            </div>
            <!-- -------list reply end-------- -->

          </li>
          </ol>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Add Comment-->
    <div class="row">
      <div  class="addCommentContainer col-lg-6 col-sm-12">

          <textarea maxlength="500"
                    [(ngModel)]="comment" class="commentText form-control"
                    placeholder="Add Comment">
          </textarea>

        <button #addCommentBtn [disabled] = "!comment || comment.length>500" (click)="addComment()" class="btn addCommentBtn btn-success">Add</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- Add Comment end-->
</div>
```

**At the end of the html there is textarea and button which I am testing to be disabled when textarea is empty.**

In component class variable name is comment which should be empty for button to be disabled. *This is assertion of my test.*

Below is Component class:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import { CommentsDataService} from "../../services/comments/comments-data.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {IComment} from "../../comments";
import {ICommentType} from "../../commentType";



declare let jQuery: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-comments',
  templateUrl: './list-comments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-comments.component.css'],
  providers:[CommentsDataService]

})
export class ListCommentsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private commentsDataService:CommentsDataService, private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  commentsData :any; // Comment Data received from service.
  comment:string; // Comment text; declaration.
  reply:string;
  commentObj:any;
  commentArrayObj:any;
  public selectedindex;
  getComments;  // Declaration of function.
  saveComment;
  getUser;




  /**
   * This Function is triggered to
   * call save function and append
   * new comment.
   * Append new comment
   *
   */
  addComment()
  {

    this.comment = this.comment.trim();
    let commentObj;
    let comment = this.comment;
    commentObj ={
      "root_id":"1",
      "target_id": "1",
      "object": this.comment,
      "time_stamp":'2 secs ago',
      "profile_image":"/../../assets/images/no-user.png",
      "first_name" : "john",
    };

    //let commentObj = this.commentObj; //Put this.commentObj to push it into this.commentData

    if( typeof this.comment == "undefined" || this.comment === '' || this.comment == null ||  this.comment == '\n' || this.comment.length>500 )
    {

      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      this.commentsData.push( commentObj );
      this.comment = ''; // Empty comment Textarea.
      return comment;

    }

  }

  /**
   *
   * Function triggered when
   * reply link is clicked
   * @param event
   * @param index
   */
  showReplyTextArea(event, index);
  showReplyTextArea(event, index)
  {


    this.selectedindex = index;
    console.log( this.selectedindex);

  }

  /**
   * Append Reply to list.
   * @param event
   * @param target_id
   */
  addReply(target_id)
  {
    let commentData = this.commentsData; //creating local variable
    let reply = this.reply; //creating local variable


    if(reply == "" || reply === '/n' || reply.length <=0 ||   reply.length > 500 )
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {


      this.commentObj = {
        root_id:1,
        target_id: target_id,
        object: reply,
        profile_image:"/../../assets/images/no-user.png",
        actor:1,
        first_name : "john"
      };

      let  commentObj = this.commentObj;

      this.commentArrayObj =[
        {
          root_id:1,
          target_id: target_id,
          object: reply,
          actor:"user:123",
          time_stamp: "2 min ago",
          first_name : "john",
          profile_image:"/../../assets/images/no-user.png"
        }
      ];


      let commentArrayObj1 = this.commentArrayObj;

      console.log('commentObj');
      console.log(commentObj);
      jQuery.each(this.commentsData, function (index, value) {

        if(value.target_id == target_id)
        {

          if(! ('comment' in commentData[index]))
          {
            commentData[index]['comment'] = commentArrayObj1;
          }
          else
          {
            commentData[index].comment.push(commentObj);
          }


        }
      })
    }

    this.reply = ''; // Empty textarea after posting reply.

  }

  ngOnInit() {


    this.commentsData =  this.commentsDataService.getComments();
    //Service call for Comments listing.
/*    this.commentsDataService.getComments().subscribe(comments=>{
        this.commentsData = comments
      }
    )*/



  }

}
```

Comment: please update the question with the component you are testing

Comment: @TomaszKula Done.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to update the view after setting the `component.comment = ''`. 
Add `fixture.detectChanges()` call before querying for your element and making the assertions.

```
fit('should  be disabled when comment is empty', () => {
      component.comment = '';

      fixture.detectChanges() // <-- add this to update the view

      addCommentBtn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button.addCommentBtn'));

      // this asserts that button matches <button disabled>Hello</button>    
      expect(addCommentBtn.nativeElement.getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual('');

      // this asserts that button matches <button>Hello</button>          
      expect(addCommentBtn.nativeElement.getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual(null);
    }
});
```

[image]

It's worth noting that you can inspect the [`DebugElement`](https://angular.io/api/core/DebugElement#attributes) without accessing the `nativeElement`.

Comment: Tomasz, this I have already added in beforeach block.
Thanks for your response. But this change has not effect. still getting Expected '' to be 'disabled'.

Comment: Adding it in the before block is too early. You must update the view after setting the comment to `''`. Unless this is the default value anyway.

Comment: Yes, I added it but still getting error. " Expected ' ' to be 'disabled' "

Comment: If I check test on any other attribute like id, it pass.

Comment: check out my edit, it explains why you should assert that the disabled attribute matches `''` or null

Comment: So, basically when button is disabled it's disabled attribute will match '' empty string and when not disabled it will match with null?

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for your time and sharing knowledge. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

here is a slight modification of the code. Try this out

```
expect(addCommentBtn.nativeElement.attributes).toContain['disabled'];
```

Comment: debugElement.properties is empty in my unit test case , any solution for this ? sample html code is "<component-name [entity]='entity'> </component-name >" and in unit test 
const comp = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('con-entity-form-content'));
expect(comp.properties.entity).toBe(component.company);
but comp.properties is {}. why?

Answer (score 2):

Another slight variation that worked for me

```
   const disabledEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.disabled-el'));
   expect(Object.keys(disabledEl.attributes)).toContain('disabled');
```

Unsure if this is related to my angular version, or to jasmine/karma, but it worked.